# How to set multiple resolutions for devices using C++ in xcode7

Tags: c++, ios

This is the current setup for my iPhone 6 plus I'm trying to set up for multiple devices but I'm new to programming I've googled many different ways to get it to work but none so far work for me.

Global.h

> ```
> #pragma once
>
> #define SMASHBROS_WINDOWWIDTH 2208
> #define SMASHBROS_WINDOWHEIGHT 1248
> ```

Game.cpp

> ```
> #include "Game.h"
> #include "Global.h"
> #include "Menu/TitleScreen.h"
> #include "Load/InitialLoadListener.h"
>
> namespace SmashBros
> {
>   Game::Game()
>   {
>       smashData = nullptr;
>       menuLoad = nullptr;
>       moduleLoad = nullptr;
>       menuScreenMgr = nullptr;
>       titleScreen = nullptr;
>       Graphics::setDefaultFontPath("assets/fonts/arial.ttf");
>   }
>
>   Game::~Game()
>   {
>       if(menuScreenMgr != nullptr)
>       {
>           delete menuScreenMgr;
>       }
>       if(titleScreen != nullptr)
>       {
>           delete titleScreen;
>       }
>       if(smashData != nullptr)
>       {
>           delete smashData;
>       }
>       if(menuLoad != nullptr)
>       {
>           delete menuLoad;
>       }
>       if(moduleLoad != nullptr)
>       {
>           delete moduleLoad;
>       }
>   }
>
>   void Game::initialize()
>   {
>       getWindow()->setSize(Vector2u(SMASHBROS_WINDOWWIDTH, SMASHBROS_WINDOWHEIGHT));
>       getWindow()->getView()->setSize(SMASHBROS_WINDOWWIDTH, SMASHBROS_WINDOWHEIGHT);
>       getWindow()->getView()->setLetterboxed(true);
>       setFPS(60);
>       menuLoad = new MenuLoad(*getWindow(), "assets/menu");
>       moduleLoad = new ModuleLoad(*getWindow(), "assets/characters", "assets/stages");
>       smashData = new SmashData(getWindow(), menuLoad, moduleLoad);
>   }
>
>   void Game::loadContent(AssetManager*assetManager)
>   {
>       InitialLoadListener* loadListener = new InitialLoadListener(getWindow());
>       menuLoad->setLoadListener(loadListener);
>
>       menuLoad->load();
>
>       moduleLoad->setCharacterSelectIconMask(&menuLoad->getCharacterSelectIconMask());
>       moduleLoad->setStageSelectIconMask(&menuLoad->getStageSelectIconMask());
>       moduleLoad->setStageSelectPreviewMask(&menuLoad->getStageSelectPreviewMask());
>       moduleLoad->load();
>
>       delete loadListener;
>
>       titleScreen = new Menu::TitleScreen(*smashData);
>       menuScreenMgr = new ScreenManager(getWindow(), titleScreen);
>   }
>
>   void Game::unloadContent(AssetManager*assetManager)
>   {
>       moduleLoad->unload();
>       menuLoad->unload();
>   }
>
>   void Game::update(ApplicationData appData)
>   {
>       appData.setAssetManager(menuLoad->getAssetManager());
>       menuScreenMgr->update(appData);
>   }
>
>   void Game::draw(ApplicationData appData, Graphics graphics) const
>   {
>       appData.setAssetManager(menuLoad->getAssetManager());
>       menuScreenMgr->draw(appData, graphics);
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: What game framework are you using?

Comment: This question is not related to `ios`. You need to add tag for your framework and remove `ios` tag.